# When does The Last: Naruto the Movie take place within Naruto Shippuden anime series and Naruto manga?

Tags: naruto

I've recently binge watched all of the original *Naruto* series and have started on *Naruto Shippuden* (around episode 20 as of now). Recently, I heard that the movie *The Last: Naruto the Movie* came out. From what I have heard, the movie has spoilers about the end of the manga (like chapter 700), but I'm currently not reading the manga (though I plan on starting).

If I were to watch the movie, when does the movie take place within *Naruto Shippuden*, if at all? I saw somewhere saying that it took place at around episode 399-400, but I also heard that a series following Shippuden is coming, so I don't know if I should watch Shippuden, *then* the upcoming series, and **then** the movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Last: Naruto the Movie takes place two years after the events of the Fourth Shinobi World War, ie two years after Chapter 699.  The last chapter of the manga, Chapter 700, shows events taking place over 10 years after the Fourth Shinobi World War. So the timeline of **The Last** falls in between chapters 699 and 700. Chronologically, the movie takes place after the Shippuden series.

As for your original question, the current episodes of Naruto:Shippuden series are fillers. So they are not based on the manga and is made specially for the anime.  But removing the filler arc, it is currently at Chapter 662 of Birth of the Ten-Tails' Jinchūriki arc.

For more Naruto related stuff, check out the [wikia site](http://naruto.wikia.com).

Comment: For those who are reading this post right now, the anime series has reached chapter 683 (Kaguya arc). There are still fillers, but it's now mixed with actual canon episodes.