# When should I watch the two latest Naruto movies?

Tags: naruto

I have completed watching all the currently released Naruto Shippuden episodes. I have completed the Naruto original series, and am on episode 436 of the subbed Naruto Shippuden series. My question is, when should I watch **The Last: Naruto the Movie** and **Boruto: Naruto the Movie**? Should I wait until I am completely done with the Shippuden series, or do I watch them now?

I have seen other answers, but none have been definitive for me. I have not read any of the Manga, nor do I plan to at this point. However, I do not want these movies to spoil any of the plot lines from the Shippuden series for me. How many episodes are left in the Shippuden series? Can someone please give me some guidance and/or information on these topics? Thank you so much!

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20657/when-does-the-last-naruto-the-movie-take-place-within-naruto-shippuden-anime-se/20664#20664

Comment: I have seen this post, but it is not definitive when it comes to the Shippuden episodes specifically.

Comment: You might want to re-read the answer. as it mentions ` the movie takes place after the Shippuden series. `